# Checking if a minimal sufficient statistic is complete

Tags: self-study, estimation, uniform-distribution, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

> Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be iid from a uniform distribution
>    $U[-\theta, 2\theta]$ with $\theta \in
>  \mathbb{R}^+$ unknown. Check if the minimal sufficient statistic of $\theta$ is complete.

I found that$$T(X) = \max \left(-X_{(1)}, \frac{X_{(n)}}{2} \right)$$is minimal sufficient but i am having trouble checking if it's complete.

My attempt: Since uniform is a location distribution, using Basu's theorem, the ancillary statistic would be the range. Since the above minimal statistic is not independent of the ancillary statistic, it is not complete. Am I right?

Comment: The range is nowhere near being an ancillary statistic, since its probability distribution depends very much on $\theta. \qquad$

Answer (score 3):

I think you should stick to the definition of a complete statistic. For that, you need to find the distribution of $T$.

For all $0<t<\theta$, the distribution function of $T$ is

\begin{align}
P_{\theta}(T\le t)&=P_{\theta}(-t\le X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\le 2t)
\\&=\left[P_{\theta}(-t<X_1<2t)\right]^n
\\&=\left(\frac{t}{\theta}\right)^n
\end{align}

So $T$ has pdf

$$f_T(t)=\frac{nt^{n-1}}{\theta^n}\mathbf1_{0<t<\theta}$$

In other words, $T$ is distributed exactly as $\max_{1\le i\le n} Y_i$ where $Y_i$'s are i.i.d $U(0,\theta)$ variables.

That $T$ is a complete statistic is a well-known fact, proved in detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699997/complete-statistic-uniform-distribution).

Comment: A common approach is to look at the derivative in $\theta$ of $\operatorname{E}_{\theta}(g(T))$.

Comment: Yes, I would have mentioned that if the OP had sought some clarification.

Comment: In the equation to find cdf, if the lhs varies up to t, how did the upper bound in rhs be 2t.

Comment: @user46697 That is not what I wrote. Observe that $-t<X_1,\ldots,X_n<2t \iff \max \left(-X_{(1)}, \frac{X_{(n)}}{2} \right)<t$. It is by the same argument you found the sufficient statistic $T$ in the first place.

Comment: If max is $<t$, then all observations will  also be $<t$. Why did you take $2t$ instead?

Comment: @user46697 It is not max of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$; it is max of $-X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}/2$. Had it been the former, it would be correct that all observations are $<t$.

Comment: Ok I get it. Thank you. After obtaining the pdf, which is the approach to "look at the derivative in $θ$ of $E(g(T)$" mentioned above?

Comment: That would become apparent once you write down $E_{\theta}(g(T))$ explicitly, realising that it is a function of $\theta$. So in order to prove/disprove completeness of $T$, you can differentiate both sides of the equation $E_{\theta}(g(T))=0$ w.r.t $\theta$ and try to show whether $g(T)$ is identically zero or not.

Answer (score 2):

[Basu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem) states that

> Let $(P_\theta; \theta \in \Theta)$ be a family of distributions on a
>   measurable space $(X, \mathcal{A})$ and $T,A$ measurable maps  from
>   $(X, \mathcal{A})$ to some measurable space $(Y, \mathcal{B})$. If $T$
>   is a boundedly complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$, and
>   $A$ is ancillary to $\theta$, then $T$ is independent of
>   $A$.

If indeed there exists an ancillary statistic that is *not* independent from the minimal sufficient statistic, then it would prove that the minimal sufficient statistic is not complete. But the range is *not* ancillary since it scales in $\theta$ (which is a scale parameter rather than a location parameter).